# SPRING BATCH : dynamic commit-interval

Tags: spring, spring-batch, flat-file

I need to know how to set programmatically (in java class not xml)a commit-interval in my batch. My program is as the following :

```
    // loop on lines information from flat file
    // treatement on line
    // commit
```

Is there a method in a library which permit to do the commit in java class ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define your own custom [CompletionPolicy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/repeat/CompletionPolicy.html). Then you set that as your `chunk-completion-policy` in your chunked step.

This [old forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/87366-manual-chunk-commit) has an example implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gives me a hint. Lokking at the example in the old forum link, I do not understand the usefulness of the class Scheduling and the invokePeek() method. It would be nice if there is their implementation.

Comment: They used `peek()` to compare the item being processed to the next item in line and determine if it should be in the same commit or not. If it should be in a different chunk, then `isComplete()` would return `true`.

Comment: In that example, the reader and the completionPolicy implementation are in the same class. In my case, I need to read lines do some processing and write in DataBase then do a commit each time a special data (in this example the date) in my line is changed. Should I separate the reader and the completionPolicy ? Is there any other example which could help me in my case ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I give more detail and my source code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922390/spring-batch-commit-interval-changing-according-to-data-in-input-file?noredirect=1#comment63299184_37922390